# sorting the network graph in a specific type

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have finally made a network graph with highcharts. I would like to sort the graph in a specific shape if possible.

Expected shape:
[image]

```js
// Add the nodes option through an event call. We want to start with the parent
// item and apply separate colors to each child element, then the same color to
// grandchildren.
Highcharts.addEvent(
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph,
    'afterSetOptions',
    function (e) {
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            i = 0,
            nodes = {};
            
        e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {

            if (link[0] === 'last01') {
                nodes['last01'] = {
                    id: 'last01',
                    marker: {
                        radius: 20
                    }
                };
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1],
                    marker: {
                        radius: 10
                    },
                    color: colors[i++]
                };
            } else if (nodes[link[0]] && nodes[link[0]].color) {
                nodes[link[1]] = {
                    id: link[1],
                    color: nodes[link[0]].color
                };
            }
        });

        e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodes).map(function (id) {
            return nodes[id];
        });
    }
);

const options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        height: '100%'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Main diag'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Router connection'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                enableSimulation: false,
                repulsiveForce: function (d, k) { 
                 return k * k * k * k / d; 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            linkFormat: ''
        },
        data: [
['last01','last02'],
['last01','medium201'],
['last01','medium202'],
['last01','medium203'],
['last01','medium204'],
['last01','medium205'],
['last01','medium206'],
['last01','medium207'],
['last01','medium208'],
['last01','medium209'],
['last01','medium210'],
['last01','medium211'],
['last01','medium212'],
['last01','medium213'],
['last01','medium214'],
['last01','medium215'],
['last01','medium216'],
['last02','last01'],
['last02','medium201'],
['last02','medium202'],
['last02','medium203'],
['last02','medium204'],
['last02','medium205'],
['last02','medium206'],
['last02','medium207'],
['last02','medium208'],
['last02','medium209'],
['last02','medium210'],
['last02','medium211'],
['last02','medium212'],
['last02','medium213'],
['last02','medium214'],
['last02','medium215'],
['last02','medium216'],
['medium201','last01'],
['medium201','last02'],
['medium201','medium101'],
['medium201','medium102'],
['medium201','medium103'],
['medium201','medium104'],
['medium202','last01'],
['medium202','last02'],
['medium202','medium101'],
['medium202','medium102'],
['medium202','medium103'],
['medium202','medium104'],
['medium203','last01'],
['medium203','last02'],
['medium203','medium101'],
['medium203','medium102'],
['medium203','medium103'],
['medium203','medium104'],
['medium204','last01'],
['medium204','last02'],
['medium204','medium101'],
['medium204','medium102'],
['medium204','medium103'],
['medium204','medium104'],
['medium205','last01'],
['medium205','last02'],
['medium205','medium101'],
['medium205','medium102'],
['medium205','medium103'],
['medium205','medium104'],
['medium206','last01'],
['medium206','last02'],
['medium206','medium101'],
['medium206','medium102'],
['medium206','medium103'],
['medium206','medium104'],
['medium207','last01'],
['medium207','last02'],
['medium207','medium101'],
['medium207','medium102'],
['medium207','medium103'],
['medium207','medium104'],
['medium208','last01'],
['medium208','last02'],
['medium208','medium101'],
['medium208','medium102'],
['medium208','medium103'],
['medium208','medium104'],
['medium209','last01'],
['medium209','last02'],
['medium209','medium101'],
['medium209','medium102'],
['medium209','medium103'],
['medium209','medium104'],
['medium210','last01'],
['medium210','last02'],
['medium210','medium101'],
['medium210','medium102'],
['medium210','medium103'],
['medium210','medium104'],
['medium211','last01'],
['medium211','last02'],
['medium211','medium101'],
['medium211','medium102'],
['medium211','medium103'],
['medium211','medium104'],
['medium212','last01'],
['medium212','last02'],
['medium212','medium101'],
['medium212','medium102'],
['medium212','medium103'],
['medium212','medium104'],
['medium213','last01'],
['medium213','last02'],
['medium213','medium101'],
['medium213','medium102'],
['medium213','medium103'],
['medium213','medium104'],
['medium214','last01'],
['medium214','last02'],
['medium214','medium101'],
['medium214','medium102'],
['medium214','medium103'],
['medium214','medium104'],
['medium215','last01'],
['medium215','last02'],
['medium215','medium101'],
['medium215','medium102'],
['medium215','medium103'],
['medium215','medium104'],
['medium216','last01'],
['medium216','last02'],
['medium216','medium101'],
['medium216','medium102'],
['medium216','medium103'],
['medium216','medium104'],
['medium101','medium201'],
['medium101','medium202'],
['medium101','medium203'],
['medium101','medium204'],
['medium101','medium205'],
['medium101','medium206'],
['medium101','medium207'],
['medium101','medium208'],
['medium101','medium209'],
['medium101','medium210'],
['medium101','medium211'],
['medium101','medium212'],
['medium101','medium213'],
['medium101','medium214'],
['medium101','medium215'],
['medium101','medium216'],
['medium101','first104'],
['medium101','first103'],
['medium101','first102'],
['medium101','first101'],
['medium102','medium201'],
['medium102','medium202'],
['medium102','medium203'],
['medium102','medium204'],
['medium102','medium205'],
['medium102','medium206'],
['medium102','medium207'],
['medium102','medium208'],
['medium102','medium209'],
['medium102','medium210'],
['medium102','medium211'],
['medium102','medium212'],
['medium102','medium213'],
['medium102','medium214'],
['medium102','medium215'],
['medium102','medium216'],
['medium102','first104'],
['medium102','first103'],
['medium102','first102'],
['medium102','first101'],
['medium103','medium201'],
['medium103','medium202'],
['medium103','medium203'],
['medium103','medium204'],
['medium103','medium205'],
['medium103','medium206'],
['medium103','medium207'],
['medium103','medium208'],
['medium103','medium209'],
['medium103','medium210'],
['medium103','medium211'],
['medium103','medium212'],
['medium103','medium213'],
['medium103','medium214'],
['medium103','medium215'],
['medium103','medium216'],
['medium103','first104'],
['medium103','first103'],
['medium103','first102'],
['medium103','first101'],
['medium104','medium201'],
['medium104','medium202'],
['medium104','medium203'],
['medium104','medium204'],
['medium104','medium205'],
['medium104','medium206'],
['medium104','medium207'],
['medium104','medium208'],
['medium104','medium209'],
['medium104','medium210'],
['medium104','medium211'],
['medium104','medium212'],
['medium104','medium213'],
['medium104','medium214'],
['medium104','medium215'],
['medium104','medium216'],
['medium104','first104'],
['medium104','first103'],
['medium104','first102'],
['medium104','first101'],
['first101','medium104'],
['first101','medium103'],
['first101','medium102'],
['first101','medium101'],
['first102','medium104'],
['first102','medium103'],
['first102','medium102'],
['first102','medium101'],
['first103','medium104'],
['first103','medium103'],
['first103','medium102'],
['first103','medium101'],
['first104','medium104'],
['first104','medium103'],
['first104','medium102'],
['first104','medium101'],

        ]
    }]
};

Highcharts.chart('container', options);
Highcharts.chart('container2', options);
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 320px;
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#container2 {
 min-width: 320px;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: It seems like you need to look at [`initialPositions`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.initialPositions)

Comment: In my opinion, you look for something like an `organization chart`: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/organization-chart or tree graph rather than `network-graph`.

Comment: There's no option to use "specific shape", but you can force some nodes' positions, see: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11464